# Chrome Headless to send message in telegram channel not working anymore

Tags: python, automation, telegram, telegram-bot, uipath

I used to use this script from command to send message to my telegram channel.. However after chrome headless was updated recently this has stopped working. Please suggest workaround..

```
"chrome path" --headless --disable-gpu https://api.telegram.org/botxyz/sendMessage?chat_id=xyz&text=my text message"
```

I've tried to modify the code but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Why would you use chrome for that? Just use some tool like curl/wget.

Comment: I am not a coder. I found this simple method to help me give alerts relating to stock market

Answer (score 0):

As I see from your question, the problem may be with the parentheses.

I don't know about the recent changes with the headless chrome, but for this particular task, you may use `curl` as well:

```
curl 'https://api.telegram.org/bot<YourBOTToken>/sendMessage?chat_id=<channel_id>&text=<text>'
```